# Issue with HTTPS Ingress on AKS - Unable to Access Service via HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-registry, ingress-nginx

I have an AKS cluster on Azure, and I've deployed my application from an ACR container registry. The assigned address for my application is in HTTP, and to resolve this, I've attempted to create an Ingress with TLS termination using a certificate from Azure Key Vault.

However, after successfully creating the Ingress, I'm still unable to access my application via HTTPS. The Ingress seems to be created, but the traffic is not being redirected correctly.

**Ingress Configuration:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.azure.com/tls-cert-keyvault-uri: https://mykeyvaultwebsite.vault.azure.net/certificates/poctodocertificat
  name: poctodoingress
  namespace: default-1705418607683
spec:
  ingressClassName: webapprouting.kubernetes.azure.com
  rules:
    - host: webclient.robotist.poc.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: todolist-frontend-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - webclient.robotist.poc.com
      secretName: mysecretname
```

**Additional Information:**

- The TLS certificate in the Azure Key Vault is verified and accessible.
- The **todolist-frontend-service** is running and accessible within the cluster on port 3000.
- The Ingress is in the correct namespace **(default-1705418607683)**.

**Observations:**

When trying to access the application via HTTPS, it doesn't work, and there are no error messages.
The Ingress status seems to indicate that it's created.

Versions:
Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS): version 1.27.7

Any assistance in identifying and resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Steps Taken:**

- Checked Ingress controller logs - no apparent issues.
- Verified TLS certificate and Key Vault settings.
- Confirmed the service is running.

**Expected Outcomes:**

- Expecting the application to be accessible via HTTPS after setting up Ingress with TLS termination.

Comment: One possible reason for this could be that the certificate is not being mounted correctly in the Ingress. You can try adding the kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true" annotation to the Ingress to enable automatic TLS certificate generation and configuration using Let's Encrypt.

Similar issue- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/570812/ingress-routing-is-not-working-with-https-on-azure

Comment: Also, make sure that the certificate is mounted correctly in the Ingress by checking the logs of the AGIC pod. You can use the following command to check the logs:

`kubectl logs -f <agic-pod-name> -n <agic-namespace>`